# Transmitting a button press 200 meters using RPi

Tags: switches, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a timing system for track meets, so I need to be able to transmit a signal -- a button press -- from the starter at the 200m start, to the finish line where the camera equipment is.

My current idea is that I have an RPi that reads in the button press at the start line, and then use an ethernet cable to connect it to the finish line. However, ethernet is only advertised to transmit a signal up to 100m long. Ethernet is also very expensive and I'd like to do this as cheap as possible.

So, I've been looking into just running a simple copper wire to transmit the button press to another RPi all the way at the finish line. I don't think I can just run a dinky little wire 200 meters and get the signal at the end.

I'm wondering the best way to do this. I'm currently thinking about somehow amplifying the signal at the start line, running some moderately thick copper wire the 200 meters, and then putting a resistor at the end and reading the signal.

One last thing to note is that the transmission needs to be near instant in order to get the most accurate times possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dinky little wire of 200m length will work without problems for a key press transmission.  You'll want a sensible line termination and clipping diodes to avoid exceeding your input voltage range.

The main problem with a dinky little wire of 200m length is how easily it becomes a broken dinky little wire.  So you need to focus on the robustness of the wire and preferably get one that is specified to withstand being stepped on.  A 200m wheel of that will actually not be trivial in size.

Personally, I'd try to see whether I can find a wireless flash trigger with 200m reach.  They do flash sync typically at 1/320s or so and will do all you need regarding transmitting a trigger signal.  Much less hassle than an actual wire.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple twisted pair 4 to 20mA current loop. There are wirless solutions available that are more convenient to use.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdmb17.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Ethernet is a digital communication link while a straight cable is not. Therefore, the range a cable ethernet can go is limited. A DC signal is not, mostly the resistance of the wire will be the issue. 2*200meters of 30AWG wire will give you a 100 ohm series resistance equivalent. It is not insignificant, but you can work with it for sure!

Noise might also be an issue over 200m. If you measure the voltage, it will be noisier that if you measure current. That being said, simply increasing the signal strength (either voltage or current) will lead to a better signal to noise ratio.

Unless you have a more constraint, I'd go with a simple wire.